# Dropzone+Codeigniter: Undefined index:FILE

Tags: codeigniter, dropzone.js

I am trying to create an upload form with Dropzone and everything works fine in the beginning: drag&drop form is shown and the previews as well. The problem comes within the controller. When I try to handle the files, the array `$_FILES` seems to be empty, and echoing it I get this:

> array (size=0)   empty
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: file
>
> Filename: controllers/excedentes.php
>
> Line Number: 118

Do you have any idea what's going on in here? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

you can use if condition over here

```
if ($files) {
  your code
} else {
  your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check the post/get parameters when submitting request to the server:
`<input type="file" name="file" />`.

Also consider checking the `post_max_size` value of your php settings on `php.ini` file and set value desired that suits you. If the size of your POST data is greater than your `post_max_size`, the $_POST and $_FILES super globals are empty.